# On-screen button for A-frame AR

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, aframe, interaction

I`m trying this for days and I need help, please! What I need is two buttons on-screen overlaying the ar-camera picture reacting on touch. I tried two a-planes inside the the camera entity and I added **cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"** to a-scene (A-Frame 0.8.0). Somehow **cursor="rayOrigin: mouse"** blocks the aframe-ar.js to open the cam.

So, is there another way, maybe creating 2 buttons via js or html to switch objects on/off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raycaster-based `cursor` component may not work within ar.js.

If you need just a simple button which will interact with the entities, just throw in a html `<button>` on the website, and react to clicks:

```
<div style='position: fixed; top: 10px; width:100%; text-align: center; z-index: 1;'>
    <button>
        HIDE OBJECTS
    </button>
</div>
<a-scene>
....
```

**JS**

```
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
  // do stuff here.
})
```

example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/rmz694a2/7/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Piotr! You`re my hero again! :)

Comment: @Can glad i could help, happy coding !